# How can I merge two bundleOf?

Tags: android, kotlin

Lets say that I have

```
val bundle = bundleOf (
   "KEY_IS_FROZEN" to false
)

val bundleSecond = bundleOf (
   "KEY_PRICE" to 50.0
)
```

How can I create bundle that would contain

```
bundleOf (
   "KEY_PRICE" to 50.0,
   "KEY_IS_FROZEN" to false
)
```

writing simple `bundle + bundleSecond` fails, I looked through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle - I tried googling `bundle kotlin add`, `bundle kotlin merge`, `bundle kotlin site:stackoverflow.com` and looked through "similar questions" above this question and so on - without any useful effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use `putAll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Bundle#putall) to put all of the entries from one `Bundle` into the receiving `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks, it allowed me to make https://github.com/streetcomplete/StreetComplete/pull/2244/commits/77eb5764fbdcf0025ed5a26a0d70689b6f599cfe for https://github.com/streetcomplete/StreetComplete/pull/2244#issuecomment-748671797